# How to right a variable length currying function or a general currying function for all type of inputs?

Tags: javascript, variadic-functions, currying, variadic, arity

```
function currying(func) {
//I need to complete this for all diiferent forms of add
}


//1st form
const add = currying(function (a, b) {
    return a + b;
})
add(1, 2) //should yield 3
add(1)(2) //should yield 3

//second form
const add = currying(function (a, b, c) {
    return a + b + c;
})
add(1, 2)(3) //should yield 6
add(1)(2)(3) //should yield 6
add(1, 2, 3) //should yield 6

//third form
const add = currying(function (a, b, c, d) {
    return a + b + c + d;
})
const a11 = add(1)
a11(2)(3)(4) //should yield 9
a11(2, 3, 4) //should yield 9
```

How to complete the top most "currying" function for all these cases? "Currying" function must return correct answer for any of these kind of function calls.

Comment: Not possible unless you know how many arguments there will be total in advance, or unless every chain has a terminating call (like `getSum`)

Comment: Some how it will be possible because I have not designed the question.

Comment: If you need the result to `===` to a number, and you don't know in advance how many arguments there will be total, it's not possible - whoever designed the question is wrong.